# Deleting Views and Shifting Content After Using Gesture

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a VStack that, through DragGesture(), .rotationEffect(), and .offset(), can move and rotate off-screen. Below the VStack is another VStack. How should I, upon the VStack moving off-screen, delete the upper VStack and shift the lower VStack upwards to the upper VStack's original position?

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    var colWidth: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("A")
            }
            .frame(width: colWidth)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 5)))
            .offset(x: offset.width * 5, y: 0)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.offset = gesture.translation
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            if abs(self.offset.width) > 100 {
                            } else {
                                self.offset = .zero
                            }
                        }
            )
            VStack {
                Text("B")
            }.frame(width: colWidth)
            .border(Color.black)
        }
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test(colWidth: 414)
    }
}
```

In this case, when A is shifted out of view, how should I delete A and move B up to the position of A?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would use a `ForEach`, so if you ever wanted to add more letters (like "C" for example), you wouldn't need to change your code.

It also makes removing very easy. All you need to do is `rows.remove(at: index)`, and the lower `VStack`s will shift up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    var colWidth: CGFloat = 414
    
    @State var rows = ["A", "B", "C"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(rows.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack {
                    Text(rows[index]) /// get the current letter
                }
                .frame(width: colWidth)
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(index != 0 ? 0 : Double(offset.width / 5))) /// only rotate if row is on top (index 0)
                .offset(x: index != 0 ? 0 : offset.width * 5, y: 0) /// only offset if row is on top (index 0)
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                            
                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                self.offset = gesture.translation
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                if abs(self.offset.width) > 100 {
                                    rows.remove(at: index)
                                }
                                self.offset = .zero
                            }
                )
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Swipe on row to remove]

---

**Edit:** Allow swipe on any row to delete

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var gestureIndex: Int?
    @State var offset = CGSize.zero
    var colWidth: CGFloat = 414

    @State var rows = ["A", "B", "C"]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(rows.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack {
                    Text(rows[index])
                }
                .frame(width: colWidth)
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(gestureIndex == index ? Double(offset.width / 5) : 0)) /// only apply rotation if row is dragged row
                .offset(x: gestureIndex == index ? offset.width * 5 : 0, y: 0) /// only apply offset if row is dragged row
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { gesture in
                                print("change: \(index)")
                                self.gestureIndex = index
                                self.offset = gesture.translation
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                if abs(self.offset.width) > 100 {
                                    rows.remove(at: index)
                                }
                                self.gestureIndex = nil
                                self.offset = .zero
                            }
                )

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer - that helped me a lot. If I want to swipe C, I would have to swipe A and B to get to C. Is there any way I can swipe C, or any other VStack, directly?